# How to dismiss keyboard in case of a modal view?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Running on iPad.
I'm presenting a view controller modally. It is using MonoTouch.Dialog to show some text input fields, buttons, etc.
When tapping a textfield, the keyboard pops up. When tapping outside the textfield I would like to dismiss the keyboard but it won't go away. I read that dismissing the keyboard is not possible when presenting as FormSheet? Is that correct?

Here's my code. The selector gets called, but the keyboard stays where it is. As the textfields are created dynamicalls I cannot/don't want to call ResignFirstResponder() on each of them but instead let the view become first responder and then resign.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
  base.ViewDidLoad (  );
UITapGestureRecognizer oTapRecognizer = new UITapGestureRecognizer (  );
oTapRecognizer.AddTarget(this, new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector("ViewTappedSelector:"));
this.View.AddGestureRecognizer ( o );
}

[Export( "ViewTappedSelector:" )]
public void ViewTapped ( UIGestureRecognizer sender )
{
    this.View.BecomeFirstResponder (  );
    this.View.ResignFirstResponder (  );
}
```

Comment: How are the text fields being created? Can the view become first responder?

Comment: Text fields are created by MT.Dialog. I think anything can become first responder...? As long as it offers me the BecomeFirstResponder() method, I call it. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I read that dismissing the keyboard is not possible when presenting as FormSheet?

This is correct. If you'd like to dismiss the keyboard while showing a modal view, you'll have present it using a different modalStyle and you could resize the view to take the same frame as a formsheet.

Comment: But that's a kludge then. Resizing the modals is not intended and only possible after they have become visible. But I'm fine with this behavior then. If Steve decided it to be like that, I'll live with it. :-)

Comment: Another sidenote: I have just realized that iPad keyboard even has a button (bottom right) to dismiss it manually.